# meaning of "endless Friends marathons"

Tags: meaning

[In an interview](https://youtu.be/1Go62PWRQ7w?t=21), Taylor Swift says

> I watch **endless Friends marathons** for comfort.

What does that mean?

[Googling it](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20%22endless%20Friends%20marathons%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&oq=define%20%22endless%20Friends%20marathons%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.3869j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) just returns similar expressions without any further explanation.

What does "endless" mean? There are 236 episodes in total. There is an end, why is it called "endless"?

Answer (score 2):

A [marathon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathon_(media)) in the context of TV shows usually refers to a long block in which the station is continuously running episodes of the same show, or shows and movies which have a common theme. (Or, in the current age of streaming media, you can make your own marathon by viewing multiple episodes of the show).

In this case, a "Friends marathon" would consist of watching multiple episodes of the [show "Friends"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends) back to back.

Comment: Thank you. Does "back to back" here means the guy in that marathon watches S01E01, S01E02, S01E03 and so on?

Comment: @PutBere "Back to back" means that you start the next episode right after you finish the previous one. It doesn't necessarily have to be in order - it usually is, but for shows without much continuity TV stations will often reorder the episodes for the marathon.

Comment: Just to add an additional word you did not ask about: you will find people referring to "binge watching", or similar phrases, to mean the same thing -- a *binge* is doing something to an excess -- eating ice cream or watching "Friends" -- and has become a common phrase to mean watching many episodes of something 'back-to-back'.

Comment: Thank you. What does "endless" mean? There are 236 episodes in total. There is an end, why is it called "endless"?

Comment: "Endless" is a hyperbolic expression for "a long time."

Comment: @PutBere  Mary is right that "endless" is hyperbolic here, but also it doesn't necessarily apply to the number of episodes in Friends, but the fact that the marathons of these episodes are constantly repeated on certain TV channels. When they get through the whole series (or selection from the series), they just start over.